# How can I delete the rows A2 except a column K?

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing something & delete the row A2 in every loop, As usually it delete the value in column K. But I want not to delete the value in column K , Because I'll use the data having column K later.
Is it possible?
I am using currently:

```
WSheet.Rows(2).Delete
```

So how can I do the same with skipping the column K.
[image]

Comment: Do you have data that need to be delete in any other column than column A? Doesn't appear on your image.

Comment: Yes! I want to delete the data from column A only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WSheet.[a2].Delete xlUp
```